# Why can a for..of / for..in loop use const while a normal for loop can only use let or var for its variable in JS?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, constants, let

In JavaScript, you can do something like this:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (const v of arr) console.log(v);
```

But in normal for loop, it gives a `TypeError`:

```js
for (const i = 0; i < 5; i++) console.log(i);

// TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
```

Shouldn't the for..of get an error as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No the `for(...of...)` loop won't get an error. Here is why:**

In the second for loop, you are editing the constant variable which is **NOT** allowed. This throws a TypeError. In the first for loop, it doesn't matter what type of variable assignment you use. The variable (`const`,`let`, `var`, or no identifier) calls on the iterator which creates a sort of isolated temporary scope. This is why you can't access the variable outside of the for loop. For example:

```js
const example = 1;
example = 2;
//TypeError

for (const someVar of Array(5)) someVar = 12;
//TypeError

{
    const num = 200;
}

const num = 150;
//This is fine because of scope
```

Answer (score 1):

In `for...of` create a loop iterating in the `arr`.

```
const x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for (const n of x) {
   console.log(n)
}
```

It will iterate over the Object or Array, and

```
for (let i = 0; i < n;i++) {}
```

Here i = 0 then i = 1 then i = 2 and so on.
That is why you cannot use CONST because (**you cannot reassign a value to const**) `i` will be reassigned.